Lightgbm ranking metrics
I used LightGBM LambdaRank, but can’t understand how to further calculate metrics from the obtained values
Dataframe
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import lightgbm as lgb

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "query_id":[i for i in range(100) for j in range(10)],
    "var1":np.random.random(size=(1000,)),
    "var2":np.random.random(size=(1000,)),
    "var3":np.random.random(size=(1000,)),
    "relevance":list(np.random.permutation([1,2,3,4,5, 6,7,8,9,10]))*100
}) 


Here is the dataframe:
query_id    var1    var2    var3    relevance
0   0   0.905357    0.894079    0.375130    5
1   0   0.547075    0.377121    0.754090    3
2   0   0.160593    0.397771    0.034981    10
3   0   0.295548    0.162948    0.549913    9
4   0   0.833037    0.233751    0.096317    7
... ... ... ... ... ...
995 99  0.188557    0.258408    0.090342    6
996 99  0.178921    0.881938    0.467198    2
997 99  0.175884    0.897310    0.992994    8
998 99  0.466874    0.400800    0.561379    1
999 99  0.035098    0.232043    0.982138    4
1000 rows × 5 columns


I split the dataset into a training set, validation set and test set

train_df = df.iloc[:600]
test_df = df.iloc[600:800]
val_df = df.iloc[800:]

qids_train = train_df.groupby("query_id")["query_id"].count().to_numpy()
X_train = train_df.drop(["query_id", "relevance"], axis=1)
y_train = train_df["relevance"]

qids_validation = validation_df.groupby("query_id")["query_id"].count().to_numpy()
X_validation = validation_df.drop(["query_id", "relevance"], axis=1)
y_validation = validation_df["relevance"]

qids_test = test_df.groupby("query_id")["query_id"].count().to_numpy()
X_test = test_df.drop(["query_id", "relevance"], axis=1)
y_test = test_df["relevance"]

Create lgb datasets
lgb_train = lgb.Dataset(X_train, label=y_train, group=qids_train)
lgb_valid = lgb.Dataset(X_validation, label=y_validation, group=qids_validation)
lgb_test = lgb.Dataset(X_test, label=y_test, group=qids_test)


Train model
param_ranking = {
    "objective": "lambdarank",
    "label_gain": [int(i) for i in range(int(max(y_train.max(), y_validation.max())) + 1)],
    "metric": ["ndcg"],
    "eval_at": 5,
    "random_state": 1,
    "verbosity": -1,
    # 'num_threads': 16,
    "learning_rate": 0.1,
}
callbacks = [
    lgb.early_stopping(20),
    lgb.log_evaluation(period=10)  
]
model_gbm = lgb.train(
    param_ranking,
    lgb_train,
    100,
    valid_sets=[lgb_train, lgb_valid],
    callbacks=callbacks,
)

Training until validation scores don't improve for 20 rounds
[10]    training's ndcg@5: 0.880126 valid_1's ndcg@5: 1
[20]    training's ndcg@5: 0.906826 valid_1's ndcg@5: 1
Early stopping, best iteration is:
[1] training's ndcg@5: 0.789559 valid_1's ndcg@5: 1


y_pred = model_gbm.predict(X_test)
X_test["predicted_ranking"] = y_pred
X_test.sort_values("predicted_ranking", ascending=False)


I'm stuck at this point and can’t calculate metrics such as map@k, hit@k, mrr, ndcg@k. If anyone can help please explain how to interpret the lgbm model predictions for further calculation of metrics on the test dataset
def hit_rate(y_true, y_pred, k=5):
    hits = 0
    for true, pred in zip(y_true, y_pred):
        top_indices = np.argsort(pred)[::-1][:k]
        if true in top_indices:
            hits += 1
    return hits / len(y_true)
hit_rate(y_test, y_pred )
0.0

I tried to calculate hitrate, but got 0
